# Make HTML5 video stop at indicated time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video element in my page. The video I want to play is having a duration of **10** minutes.

I have to play the part of the video from minute **1** to minute **5**.
I can start it from a particular time by setting its `currentTime` property.
But how can I stop the video at a particular time jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: by attaching an event listener on timeupdate event

Answer (score 64, accepted):

TL;DR: Simply listen on [`"timeupdate"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents):

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 5 * 60) {
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

---

The usual way to wait for something in JavaScript is to wait for an event or a timeout. A timeout is out of question in this case, the user might pause the video on his own. In this case the stop wouldn't be on your specific time, but earlier.

Checking the time regularly is also too costly: you either check too often (and therefore waste precious processing power) or not often enough and therefore you won't stop at the correct time.

However `currentTime` is a checkable property, and to our luck, there's the `timeupdate` event for media elements, which is described as follows:

> The current playback position changed as part of normal playback or in an especially interesting way, for example discontinuously.

This concludes that you can simply listen on `timeupdate` and then check whether you've passed the mark:

```
// listen on the event
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    // check whether we have passed 5 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(this.currentTime >= 5 * 60) {
        // pause the playback
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that this will pause whenever the user tries to skip past 5 minutes. If you want to allow skips and only initially pause the video beyond the 5 minute mark, either remove the event listener or introduce some kind of flag:

```
var pausing_function = function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 5 * 60) {
        this.pause();

        // remove the event listener after you paused the playback
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",pausing_function);
    }
};

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", pausing_function);
```

Comment: currentTime is in seconds, not miliseconds

Comment: @apostl3pol: Thanks. Note that you can suggest edits if you find an old answer. That way, you can improve (or fix) old answers, even if the original author isn't active anymore.

Comment: is it neccesary to do var pausing_function = function() {}? couldnt it be function pausing_function(){}

Comment: @DGoiko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 5):

The `timeupdate` event is what you are looking for, but it only fires at about 2 fps which is too slow to stop at precise times.

For those cases I used `requestAnimationFrame` which fires at 60 fps and decreased the endTime a little which fixes small "lag hops":

```
const onTimeUpdate = () => {
    if (video.currentTime >= (endTime - 0.05)) {
      video.pause()
    } else {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(onTimeUpdate)
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(onTimeUpdate)
```

Comment: You would only want to do this when you're close to the `currentTime` you want to pause at. On a typical smart TV with a fairly slow CPU, polling every frame will have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of an inbuilt way, but one way would be to use the setInterval Function and check the currentTime for the video and then stop playback

```
var myVid=document.getElementById("video1");
var timer= setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer()
  {
    if(myVid.currentTime == 5* 60)
    {
       myVid.pause();
       window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So as below

```
<video id="myVid">
<source></source> <!--Whatever source here -->
</video>
```

using Above HTML attach an Event

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVid");
vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
// Check you time here and
if(t >= 300000) //Where t = CurrentTime
{
vid.stop();// Stop the Video
}
});
```

This is the right way of doing it.

Comment: `timeupdate` triggers at a random frequency from 4 to 20Hz, `currentTime` will never be equal to 30000. You have to use the '>' comparison instead of the `===`

Comment: @KeitIG agreed. Made the change accordingly.

Comment: I tried this and it never calls the timeupdate function.

Comment: note - it's vid.pause() ... not vid.stop()