# How to stop (not pause) html5 video with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a page that plays a short clip from a video (full video isn't supposed to be available on this page) using the html5 video tag.  If a user visits the page and navigates back, when they visit a second time (within several minutes), the video doesn't play.  I believe it is because I am using jQuery to pause the video after 7 seconds:

```
$('#playButton').click(function(event){
$('#theVideo').get(0).play()    
setTimeout(function(){$('#theVideo').get(0).pause() }, 7000);
});
```

I tried using `.stop()` as suggested in the unaccepted answer on this question:
[Make HTML5 video stop at indicated time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355952/make-html5-video-stop-at-indicated-time)

This code does not work:

```
// doesn't work
setTimeout(function(){$('#theVideo').get(0).stop()  }, 7000);
// also doesn't work
setTimeout(function(){$('#theVideo').stop() }, 7000);
```

I've referenced Mozilla's documentation.  The only quasi-official documentation I've found for jQuery and HTML5 video is from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

It does not reference a "stop" method.  Should I expect .stop() to work, or do I need to find another solution?

My video code:

```
<video playsinline id='theVideo' poster=''>
<source src='http://somedomain/subfolder/playlist.m3u8'>
</video>
<div id="playButton">PLAY</div>
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no `.stop()`. You just can pause it...

But you also can set the `currentTime` back to zero (begining of the file)...
That will be nice to have it ready to play again on subsequent `#playButton` click.

That would be:

```
$('#playButton').click(function(event){
  $('#theVideo').get(0).play(); 
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#theVideo').get(0).pause();
    $('#theVideo').get(0).currentTime = 0;
  }, 7000);
});
```

Now, *«If a user visits the page and navigates back»*... Holà!! Using the browser's back button? Nothing you can do here. The JavaScript is **not** ran like a normal page load here. Nothing can happen "on back".

Answer (score 17):

You can stop it with pause and currentTime.

```
var media = $("#video-id").get(0);
media.pause();
media.currentTime = 0;
```

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs

Answer (score 3):

Set the srcObject to null.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

window.location.reload(false); is your friend here.  With this (extra buttons added from what I found on https://levelup.gitconnected.com/data-stream-from-your-webcam-and-microphone-videochat-with-javascript-step-1-29895b70808b) when I click on my stop button the light next to my camera goes out and if I then click on start I am again prompted to allow access to the media devices.  YMMV.

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  document.addEventListener('click', async event => {
    if (event.target.id === 'start button') {
      const stream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
      const video = document.getElementById('video');
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.pause();
    }
    if (event.target.id === 'play button') {
      video.play();
    }
    if (event.target.id === 'pause button') {
      video.pause();
    }
    if (event.target.id === 'stop button') {
      window.location.reload(false);
    }
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//playdemo
function playdemo(){
    video.src="url.mp4";
    video.play();
}
//stopdemo
function stopdemo(){
    video.src="";
}
```